# What is the best place to store static assets (files) in Rails ( pdf forms, xls files, etc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a bunch of static assets ( not jpg, css, & js) - rather files like  pdf forms, xls that I need to serve to users. They rarely change. Before I used to store them in public folder, but with the introduction of the assets pipeline in rails 3.1 what is the best place to store files like that now now?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually I just tested it by creating a folder in app/assets/files and sticking my xls files in there, and rake assets:precompile task just picked it up.

Also this needs to be added for Rails < 3.1:

```
    # Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = true
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/files"
```

Comment: one gotcha on this - the file must be added prior to deploy-time. If you are precompiling (which you pretty much have to for performance reasons) you cannot add them in production (I.e user uploaded).

Comment: Yep that's fine - these are asset files in the same sense as my js or css files. These are forms/brochures that we provide to users. They rarely change, after the initial deployment, just like css or js. For user uploaded content we have a different workflow.

Answer (score 8):

The best place for items like this is still in the `/public` directory, remember to have your web server serve these assets directly also.

The assets directory is only needed if you want to take advantage of the asset pipeline. The asset pipeline handles things from compressing and compiling `.coffee` and `.less` or `sass` files to compressing your js and css into one file so your webserver only has to serve one file for each.

When you compile your assets with the rake task `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` they are moved to your public directory anyhow.

Comment: Joseph, I'm actually using the pipeline. Sticking it into public doesn't seem consistent. Jsut wondering how can I serve static assets from my app similar to image or scss assets