# Assets vs Public for static videos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, ruby-on-rails-4, html5-video, asset-pipeline

I have a static video in my rails application. I have two copies of it: one stored in `assets/videos` and one stored in `public`. For some reason the video stored in the `assets` folder loads much slower than the video stored in the `public` folder.

1. Does anyone know why?
2. What is the best practice? Is it bad practice to put it in `public`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know why?

Because `public` folder is the first place which serves incoming request. If the folder/file doesn't found in that folder, it will be forwarded to rails.

> What is the best practice? Is it bad practice to put it in public?

it depends. If you want to use rails features like accessing videos folder with `assets_path` or may be like converting videos from one format to two with some rails script or you want restrict videos to some countries or people/user then you should put NOT put in `public` folder. 
That's all.

Comment: Thats a very interesting point to consider about restricting videos. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

> The assets directory is only needed **if you want to take advantage of
>   the asset pipeline.** The asset pipeline handles things from
>   compressing and compiling .coffee and .less or sass files to
>   compressing your js and css into one file so your webserver only has
>   to serve one file for each.
>
> **When you compile your assets with the "rake task bundle exec rake assets:precompile" they are moved to your public directory anyhow**

Check this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/8581316/1231365

So it's better to keep your videos in the public folder.

Comment: Both answers were very good. You raised some very good points about videos and precompiling. Thanks.